# Is it true that properties and ivars are not initially set to nil or zero when building for AdHoc or Distribution / Release?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Someone just told me that, but I can hardly believe it. My app on the AppStore would have crashed all the time without this.

So is this true?

Comment: I've never heard this - what source did they cite? Should be easy to verify especially with an Adhoc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope;  ivars are always initialized to zero/0/nil/NULL/Nil upon allocation.

In fact, when an Objective-C object is allocated, the memory associated with the allocation is effectively `bzero()`d.

Comment: Thank you so much for this confirmation. Thought I need to see a doctor.